# SQL Developer, want to create a Front End for Automation of creation of Unix Scripts

Tags: unix, automation, oracle10g, purge

We perform daily purging of Oracle database using Unix shell scripts.
I want to automate the procedure of making scripts.
Which would be the best and efficient way of making a front end connecting my Oracle Database. I use Oracle 10g PL/SQL Developer and expert in SQL.
I am comfortable with ADO.NET. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to (1) create a front end to connect to the database or (2) automate the procedure of "making scripts" or (3) automate the daily purging?

If you already have shell scripts that do the purging, then the easiest/quickest option is to add those scripts to the cron [[1]](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) [[2]](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/12176.aspx) job, with interval for daily (`0 X * * *` where X is the hour of the day).